# magento rabitMQ error: Broken pipe or closed connection

Tags: magento2, rabbit-mq

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPConnectionClosedException: Broken pipe or closed connection in /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(369): PhpAmqpLib\Wire\IO\StreamIO->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Connection/AbstractConnection.php(493): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->write('\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\v\x00\x14\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AbstractChannel.php(244): PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AbstractConnection->send_channel_method_frame(1, Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPWriter))
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Channel/AMQPChannel.php(185): PhpAmqpLib\Channel\AbstractChannel->send_method_frame(Array, Object(PhpAmqpLib\Wire\AMQPWriter))
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/fra in /var/www/html/vendor/php-amqplib/php-amqplib/PhpAmqpLib/Wire/IO/StreamIO.php on line 228
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for above issue is:

1.download https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/releases/download/3.8.17/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.8.17.8f537ac.ez into /plugins folder inside the rabbitmq container

2. ssh into rabbitmq container and run `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange`

My commands are:

Fisrt check your rabbitmq container id by `docker ps` then copy plugin file from local files to container. Then ssh your container and finally activate your plugin.

```
    1. docker cp "/home/hassan/Downloads/rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange-3.8.17.8f537ac.ez" 599b5b6f509e:"/plugins"
2. docker exec -it 599b5b6f509e /bin/bash
    3. rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange
```

599b5b6f509e is my rabitmq container id. mightbe helpful or gave starting point to fix for someone facing this issue